# React Hooks useState Array empty with states rendered in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a situation where i can successfully dispatch my states with reducers and i can render it in my component

Here the relevant code

in my `action/index.js`

```
export const receivedLeaguesList = json => ({
  type: RECEIVE_LEAGUES_LIST,
  json: json
});

export function fetchLeaguesList() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestLeaguesList());
      return axios
        .get("https://www.api-football.com/demo/v2/leagues/")
        .then(res => {
          let leagues = res.data.api.leagues;
          dispatch(receivedLeaguesList(leagues));
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
}
```

my `reducers/index.js`

```
import { REQUEST_LEAGUES_LIST, RECEIVE_LEAGUES_LIST } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  leaguesList: [],
  isLeagueListLoading: false
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_LEAGUES_LIST:
      return { ...state, isLeagueListLoading: true };
    case RECEIVE_LEAGUES_LIST:
      return { ...state, leaguesList: action.json, isLeagueListLoading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

in my component `component/Leagues.js`

```
let Leagues = ({ leaguesList, loading, getList }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getList();
  }, [getList]);


  const [itemsLeagues] = useState([leaguesList]);

  console.log("league list", itemsLeagues);

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getList: fetchLeaguesList
};
```

I have reproduced the demo here => https://codesandbox.io/s/select-demo-71u7h?

I can render my `leaguesList` states in my component doing the map, but why when

```
  const [itemsLeagues] = useState([leaguesList]);

  console.log("league list", itemsLeagues);
```

returns an empty array ?

See the image[image]

Comment: Why would you store props in state?

Comment: Could it be the CORS issue? Are you getting response from the API in the first place?

Comment: What's the issue with that? i use CORS Unblock google extension to allow

Comment: It seems @Kotofenum is right, I just looked at the network tab and it shows requests to https://www.api-football.com/demo/v2/leagues/ fail

Comment: In your codesandbox demo I'm getting an exception caused by the request being blocked by CORS policy. Do you have the same issue in your local environment?

Comment: CORS Unblock has to be activated to allow the request,  that's why you have the issue in your local environment, it is a Google extension that i use

Comment: @Koala7 I just checked it like that: in axios catch, I call dispatch as the request would be fine and it works! Are you sure your extension works? How could it work if the server has to add `access-control-allow-origin` header? If we could just install an extension and got access to any API why we needed CORS then?

Comment: @vitkarpov CORS is intended to protect users from possible vulnerabilities, this plugin just helps you to avoid that security policy at your own risk. Anyway, in some cases after avoiding CORS you'll eventually stumble upon CORB, which can be skipped only if you're starting the browser disabling all the security checks.

Comment: We as developers should use these options **only** for testing purposes.

Comment: @Kotofenum makes sense, thanks. It modifies a response headers on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting useState's init value wrong:

```
 const [itemsLeagues] = useState(leaguesList);
```

instead of

```
 const [itemsLeagues] = useState([leaguesList]);
```

The return value of useState isn't the value itself, but the array of value and mutator:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([42, 43])
// here's value equals [42, 43]
```

So if you were trying to destructure the wrapping array you passed to useState(), you should use it like this (though you don't need it):

```
const [[itemsLeagues]] = useState([leaguesList]);
```